# PayPal REST API Recurring Payments, but strategy for 1 payment / 6 months?

Tags: rest, api, paypal, payment, recurring

I have a nicely working recurring payments setup with the PayPal REST API. However, I am scratching my head how to get this payment strategy to work:

__> 6 month long subscription cycle, infinitely repeating.
__> one-time payment for the 6-month period paid at start of subscription.

For this I assume it would be an INFINITE setting, but the API does not have a setting for 6-months, only billing cycles for DAY, WEEK, MONTH, and YEAR.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to set the `frequency_interval` to 6 and the `frequency` to `MONTH` in the billing plan's [payment definition](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans#definition-payment_definition).

> **frequency_interval** *string*
>
> The interval at which the customer can be charged. Value cannot be greater than 12 months.